# No puedo cerrar el formulario padre y formulario hijo desde el formulario hijo

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Tengo un proyecto que contiene un login que al ingresar como administrador se muestra una ventana MDI, que es una ventana de configuración y desde ahí se puede abrir la ventana principal (quedan las dos abiertas). En la ventana principal tengo un boton que cierra la sesión volviendo a la ventana del login y (lo que deseo que haga el software) cierra las ventanas MDI y principal, pero solo me cierra la ventana principal y abre la ventana de login. 
Probe realizando una instancia de la ventana MDI de la siguiente Manera:

```
Dim panel As New Panel_MDI()
panel.Close()
Me.Close()
```

pero esto no me funciona.

Me di cuenta que cuando realice algunos ajustes, las instancias a esos formularios comenzaron a fallar. 
Lo que realice es que, pase un argumento desde el login hasta la pantalla principal, creando un New que recibe argumentos.

```
Private nombre As String

Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    abrir_controlProduccion()
    abrir_eTata()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal nom As String)
    Me.New()
    nombre = nom
End Sub
```

Ese codigo es del formulario principal, el del formulario MDI es igual.

¿Puede ser que al crear nuevas instancias no estoy cerrando la que quiero sino otra?

Answer (score 1):

Logre solucionar el problema.

Efectivamente no estaba cerrando la misma instancia, asi que modifique el codigo para obtener la instancia del formulario padre de la siguiente manera:

En el panel MDI agrego la siguiente linea para pasar la instancia del padre al hijo.

```
Dim panel As New PanelPrincipal()
panel.Show(Me)
```

Luego en el hijo escribi el siguiente código:

```
Login.Show()
CType(Me.Owner, Panel_MDI).Close()
Me.Close()
```